# What is wrong with my Postgres statement?

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, manager_id
    CASE manager_id
        WHEN manager_id IS null THEN "pip"
        End manager_id
    FROM assgnssql.employees;
```

I am trying to select list of employees, but i know some employees do not have manager_id, for these employees without manager_id (null) i want the result to display "pip" while for the rest it displays original info.

Comment: For one thing, you are using double quotes for a string, when the accepted delimiter is single quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you want is probably:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, manager_id
        (CASE WHEN manager_id IS null THEN 'pip' ELSE manager_id
         END) as manager_id
FROM assgnssql.employees;
```

Or more simply:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, manager_id
       COALESCE(manager_id, 'pip') as manager_id
FROM assgnssql.employees;
```

The two significant issues are:

- Your `CASE` syntax is messed up.  Either you use comparisons or you have `CASE <value>`, but not both.
- Strings are delimited by single quotes.

Comment: Thanks everybody for all the feedback and pointers. I was able to edit @Gordon Linoff answer to do what i wanted.